# submit new record to db give me invalid literal for int

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

guys im working on django-rest-framwork . now im creating some new record to db at( store_product ) table when im submitting new data when i press POST button i get this error

why i get this error ? !!

```
ValueError at /store/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/store/
Django Version: 2.0.1
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
Exception Location: /home/mohammadreza/www/html/academy/uenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py in get_prep_value, line 947
Python Executable:  /home/mohammadreza/www/html/academy/uenv/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.6.4
Python Path:    
['/home/mohammadreza/www/html/academy/api/academy',
 '/home/mohammadreza/www/html/academy/uenv/lib/python36.zip',
 '/home/mohammadreza/www/html/academy/uenv/lib/python3.6',
 '/home/mohammadreza/www/html/academy/uenv/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6',
 '/home/mohammadreza/www/html/academy/uenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 28 Jan 2018 11:54:13 +0330
```

**INFO**
here is my serializer.py file

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Product


class StoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'product_id',
            'author',
            'category',
            'title',
            'description',
            'filepath',
            'created_date',
            'updated_date',
        ]
        read_only_fields = ['product_id', 'created_date', 'updated_date','author']



    def validate_title(self,value):
        qs = Product.objects.filter(title__iexact=value)
        if self.instance:
            qs.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk)
        if qs.exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("this title is already used")
        return value
```

and here is my view.py file

```
from rest_framework import generics
from .serializers import StoreSerializer
from .models import Product


class StoreCreateApiView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'pk'
    serializer_class = StoreSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Product.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author = self.request.user)
```

and it is my model for this model objet

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, default='')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,db_index=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='cat_id')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    filepath = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

json: (will POST)

{
    "category": 2,
    "title": "python new",
    "description": "new python",
    "filepath": ""
}

Comment: What data do you post? Can you add json?

Comment: yes  i added right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like problem with `AutoField`. AutoField is [IntegerField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#autofield), so `default=''` raise the error, remove this argument:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```